# Append <li> element to <ul> and add click event for each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'd like to add a series of `<li>` elements to a `<ul>`, and add a click event to each one, programmatically.

I'm not sure how to do this, at least not in a neat, jQueryish way.

This is my existing code:

```
<ul id="saved-list"></ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.each(all_objects, function() {{
    var list_route = "<li><a href='#saved-route'>" + this.text + "</a></li>";
    $('#saved-list').append(list_route);      
    // add unique id (this.id) to item and click event here?
    // pseudocode - onclick: alert(this.id);
});
$('#saved-list').refresh('listview'); // jquery mobile list refresh
</script>
```

Please could someone advise how to add a click event to each list item programmatically?

UPDATE: I need to do something slightly different for each list item (let's just say an alert) - apologies for not making this clear.

Comment: You're missing a quote on your ul id attribute, and no script block around your scripting. Bad copy/paste?

Answer (score 15):

You're better off using [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) than worrying about creating a `.click()` handler on every element you create. Something like this:

```
$('#saved-list').delegate('li', 'click', function () {
    // do stuff on click
});
```

You only have to bind this click listener once, and it will work for every `<li>` that is a descendant of the element with ID `saved-list`.

---

If you do want to create a separate click handler for every `<li>` (I don't recommend this though) here's a nice way to do it:

```
$.each(all_objects, function() {
    var $a = $('<a/>', {
        href: '#saved-route',
        text: this.text
    });

    var $li = $('<li/>', {
        click: function () {
            // do stuff on click
        }
    }).append($a);

    $('#saved-list').append($li);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear, I need to do something different for each of the li elements. (Have updated qu.)

Comment: That looks nice, thank you. Out of interest, why don't you recommend creating a separate click handler for each list element?

Comment: @phil that's not necessarily a problem when using `.live()` or `.delegate()`. The click handler function can behave differently depending on the element that was clicked.

Comment: I generally prefer to use `.live()` or `.delegate()` over `.bind()` (or its equivalents) to try to keep the number of event listeners to a minimum. Many event listeners can start bogging down the page, especially in older browsers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629803/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782399/

Comment: If you're executing the exact same logic on a particular event (or set of events) on many elements, it's simply lighter weight to create a single event listener on some common ancestor, rather than create a listener on every single element your interested in. Additionally, with `.live()` or `.delegate()` on a common ancestor, you don't have to to worry about re-binding listeners to elements that are added. This is another big win, and definitely applies in your case.

Answer (score 6):

Don't.

Rather than binding a new event handler for each element (which could become quite expensive), bind a single event handler to `#saved-list`, which is a common ancestor.  Event bubbling means that ancestor elements are notified of events on their descendants, so you can handle events there instead of on the originating element.

Something like this...

```
$.each(all_objects, function() {{
    var list_route = "<li><a href='#saved-route'>" + this.text + "</a></li>";
    $('#saved-list').append(list_route);      
});
$('#saved-list').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
    // do something here each time a descendant li is clicked
});
```

See [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate)

Answer (score 4):

@Matt Ball is pretty close to the answer here, but I will add a little more clearly that you can do different things with the delegate depending on what element was clicked:

```
<ul id="saved-list"></ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $savedList = $("#saved-list");
$.each(all_objects, function() {
    $savedList.append("<li><a href='#saved-route'>" + this.text + "</a></li>");
});
$savedList.delegate("li", "click", function (e) {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

$('#saved-list').refresh('listview'); // jquery mobile list refresh

Note that in the delegate `this` is still referring to the `li` that was clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it enough to add this in (or after) your current loop?

`$('#saved-list li').click(function(){ alert('hello'); });`

Answer (score 1):

hello phil in jquery you can create dom object without adding them as text to the dom.
this will give you a chans to manipulate them before they are added (and after to).

```
$("<li />")
  .append(
    $("<a />")
     .attr("href" ,"#saved-route")
     .text(this.text))
  .click(function() {
    // your click event
  })
  .appendTo("#saved-list");
```

Comment: That's not right, you're adding the `href` attribute onto the `<li>` and haven't created an `<a>` at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `live` function, the downfall is that you might need some mechanism to determine exactly which of the `li` items that have been clicked:

```
$("#saved-list li").live('click', function() {
    //act on click
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) exists.

```
$.each(all_objects, function(index) {{
    $("#saved-list").append("<li id='item" + index + "'><a href='#saved-route'>" + this.text + "</a></li>");
    $("#saved-list li").bind("click", function() {
        alert("Clicked on " + this.id);
    });
});
```

Also, this way is very easy to create different clicks for each item:

```
$("#saved-list li#item1").bind(...)
$("#saved-list li#item2").bind(...)
$("#saved-list li#item3").bind(...)
```

Comment: `.bind('click', ...)` is the same thing as `.click(...)`.

Comment: No problem; just pointing it out since `.click()` is more concise.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(all_objects, function() {{
    var list_route = "<li><a href='#saved-route'>" + this.text + "</a></li>";
    var newLi = $(list_route);
    newLi.click( function(){} ).attr("id","foo");
    //if you want the a
    newLi.find("a").click( function(){} ).attr("id","foo");

    $('#saved-list').append(newLi);              
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.click` function will bind a click handler function to any given element.  As the comments in your code mention you can use the ID or other means to select the item after it's been DOM-ized but another way to do this is simply to reference the variable that contains the element you want to bind.

Example:

```
var li = $('<li />');
li.click(function() { ... });
```

This is probably somewhat stylistic, but one of the features of jQuery is that it is chainable.  This means that jQuery function calls always return a reference to the wrapped set of jQuery itself.  Using the chainable aspect, you could re-write the above code like so:

```
var list = $('#saved-list'); $.each(all_objects, function(i, item) {{
    list.append(
        $('<li />')
            .append(
                $('<a />').text(item.text)
            )
            .click(function() { ... } );
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know what this `$('#saved-list').refresh('listview')` business is about, the following might be what you're looking for:

```
var listItemEls = all_objects.map(function () {
    return $('<li id="' + this.id + '"><a href="#saved-route">' + this.text + '</a></li>')
           .click(function (e) {
               // do whatever here
           })
           .get();
});

$('#saved-list').append(listItemEls);
```

Note that we avoid appending to the DOM until the last minute, because appending is expensive.

As other posters mention, using a delegated click handler is a better approach, generally. That would look something like

```
var listItemEls = all_objects.map(function () {
    return $('<li id="' + this.id + '"><a href="#saved-route">' + this.text + '</a></li>')
           .get();
});

$('#saved-list').append(listItemEls)
                .delegate("li", "click", function (e) {
                    // do stuff here.
                });
```