# jQuery Mobile Listview - list item onClick never fires in Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, jquery-mobile, cordova

In a jQuery Mobile `listview`, I have a series of items:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="lv_systems" data-inset="true">
  <li><a href="#page2" data-id="sys1">System 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#page2" data-id="sys2">System 2</a></li>
    ....
</ul>
```

In the `$(document).ready()`, I add a click handlers to each `<a>` like this (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111650/append-li-element-to-ul-and-add-click-event-for-each)) (`#select_system` is the page name):

```
$(document).ready( function () {         

$('#select_system').live ('pagecreate', function(){
    $('#lv_systems').delegate('li', 'click', function(){
             alert('list item clicked');
    });
});
    $('#lv_systems').listview('refresh');
});
```

Testing this code works great when testing in a browser (Chrome and Safari), but in the Android Emulator with PhoneGap, the alert message is never displayed which makes it look like the event binding is incorrect.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Memo to self: [RTFM](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/api/events.html).

Instead of binding to `click` with delegate, bind to `vclick`, i.e.

```
....
$('#lv_systems').delegate('li', 'vclick', function(){
....
```

Per the documentation,

> Normalized event for handling touch or mouse `click` events